# (linux) non-dynamic struct array use Rss memory when memset use; why?

Tags: linux, memory-management

here is my code

```
struct test oops[4][2][3][40960];  // global struct (maybe .data section)
...
{
...
//memset(oops, 0, sizeof(struct test) * 40960 * 3 * 2 * 4);
...
}
```

have question.

when i use memset,

cat /proc/PID/smaps

```
...
Size:             756480 kB
Rss:              721208 kB
Pss:              721208 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:    721208 kB
Referenced:       361252 kB
Anonymous:        721208 kB
AnonHugePages:      6144 kB
Swap:              35272 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
...
```

but, not use memset

```
Size:             756480 kB
Rss:                2048 kB
Pss:                2048 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:      2048 kB
Referenced:         2048 kB
Anonymous:          2048 kB
AnonHugePages:      2048 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

why memset use RSS?

and what is mean Pss, Private_dirty, Referenced, Anonymous ?

global struct maybe set '0', but i want to Explicit initialization.

help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without memset you never use the memory referenced by "oops". 
The linux kernel do not reserve memory pages for you until you access the memory the first time.

Size is the whole "accessible" memory size for your program.
RSS is the memory in your program which really exists (this doesn't mean the sum of all RSS is total memory used RSS also count shared memory).

memset touches every byte in your array, which forces the kernel to reserve the memory for you and put it into the RSS section.

memset don't reserve more memory it just used it the first time.

Additional infos: [Getting information about a process' memory usage from /proc/pid/smaps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/getting-information-about-a-process-memory-usage-from-proc-pid-smaps)

Comment: I can without memset access "oops", 
ex) `oops[0][1][2][5].test = 1;` it's success... (and then smaps is whiout memset same)
what different put it into the RSS section, or not into